# Angular Js groupby some specific values in fixed order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array listed as listed below

```
list = [
{
'id':1,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'test2',
'group':'php'
},{
'id':3,
'name':'test3',
'group':'nodejs'
},{
'id':4,
'name':'test4',
'group':'php'
},{
'id':5,
'name':'test5',
'group':'nodejs'
},{
'id':6,
'name':'test6',
'group':'angularjs'
}
]
```

I want to get list in fixed order of the angularjs,php and nodejs as below.

```
list = [
{
'id':1,
'name':'nitin',
'group':'angularjs'
},{
'id':6,
'name':'test6',
'group':'angularjs'
},
{
'id':2,
'name':'test2',
'group':'php'
},{
'id':4,
'name':'test4',
'group':'php'
},
{
'id':3,
'name':'test3',
'group':'nodejs'
},{
'id':5,
'name':'test5',
'group':'nodejs'
}]
```

I have tried it by taking all different ng-repeat based on each condition but i want it in single ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use custom filter (if i understand your req. correctly):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list |orderBy:myFilter">
```

---

```
  $scope.myFilter= function(item){
     switch(item.id){
       case 1:return 1;
       case 6:return 2;
       case 2: return 3;
       case 4 :return 4;
       .....................
          }
        }
```

Comment: i have added one more field in my array which is integer so based on that i resolve my problem.. thanks for your ans